# Cannot sign applications in XCode 6

Tags: xcode, signing, xcode6gm

I have just upgraded from XCode 5.1 to XCode 6.0 GM and can no longer sign my applications for ad-hoc deployment. I perform the following steps:

1. I open Window -> Organizer and select "Archives"
2. I select an archive (either one I have built from XCode 5.1, or one I have built from XCode 6).
3. I click "Export".
4. I click "Save for Ad Hoc Deployment" and click "Next"
5. I select my Development Team and click "Choose"
6. I receive the below error.

Previously this worked (I signed an application last night, and upgraded this morning), so any ideas would be gratefully received.

[image: Error text]

### ERROR TEXT

> You are not allowed to perform this operation. Please check with one of your Team Admins, or, if you need further assistance, please contact Apple Developer Program Support.

### Account Page

Here is the info from my XCode account page.

[image]

Comment: I'm running both XCode 5.1 and 6.0 concurrently. I had to use 5.1 to compile with. You may need to redo your ad hoc provisioning profile for 6.0.

Comment: You need to reimport your provision profile and signing identity. It should be a .developerprofile file. It should be under accounts under XCode preferences. You can see all your developer/member info. I'm assuming you're an agent?

Comment: @AmitApollo I'm a Member, not an Agent - I've added a screenshot to the question with my (redacted) details. I should add that I've tried removing the account and re-adding it through this screen, but with no joy.

Comment: Hi @RB did you get any luck on this because I am facing same problem

Comment: @Bhavesh. No - in the end I did all my signing with XCode 5. I'm going to look again once XCode 6 has been out for a couple of months.

Comment: Ok thanks for reply but this is too much.

Comment: Look this answer to create ipa from command line
http://stackoverflow.com/a/26067132/3791659

Answer (score 4):

You need to reimport your provision profile and signing identity. It should be a .developerprofile file. It should be under accounts under XCode preferences. You can see all your developer/member info. I'm assuming you're an agent?

[image: see here]

Comment: Where can I download the ".developerprofile" file from. I can't find it on the Apple Member Center website?

Answer (score 4):

In the end I installed XCode 5.1 and 6 side-by-side. I could then use 5.1 to sign archives created from 6. It's a bit of a faff, but I'm going to assume that it's because 6 is still beta...

Answer (score 4):

Got same issue with Xcode 6.0.1

Creating a new Provisioning profile (Development & Distribution) resolved the issue for me.

Comment: Newbie is blind:  Where is Development & Distribution in Xcode 6?

Comment: I'm also instructed to enter a "Company identifier" and can't find that field in Xcode 6.  Hint?  Thanks.

Comment: @Rishabh bro can you please give me create certificate distribution for using App by swift xcode 7?